# removing the vertical lines in \bitbox

Tags: tables, packages

```
\begin{center}
\begin{bytefield}{64}
\bitbox{12}{\textbf{Made Classification}} & \bitbox{8}{Water} & \bitbox{8}{Air} & \bitbox{16}{Chromium} \\

\bitbox{12}{\textbf{Classification Control}} & \bitbox{4}{NNG} & \bitbox{4}{On/off}& \bitbox{4}{NNG}& \bitbox{4}{On/off}& \bitbox{8}{NNG} & \bitbox{8}{On/off}\\

\bitbox{12}{\textbf{Compressing Interval}} & \bitbox{2}{R} & \bitbox{2}{S}& \bitbox{2}{R}&\bitbox{2}{S}& \bitbox{2}{R} & \bitbox{2}{S}& \bitbox{2}{R} & \bitbox{2} {S}& \bitbox{4}{R} & \bitbox{4}{S}& \bitbox{4}{R} & \bitbox{4}{S}\\

\bitbox{12}{\textbf{Compatibility Fan}} & \bitbox{1}{V} & \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{1}{V}& \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{1}{V} & \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{1}{V}& \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{1}{V} & \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{1}{V}& \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{1}{V} & \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{1}{V}& \bitbox{1}{F}& \bitbox{2}{V} & \bitbox{2}{F}& \bitbox{2}{V}& \bitbox{2}{F}& \bitbox{2}{V} & \bitbox{2}{F}& \bitbox{2}{V}& \bitbox {2}{F}\\

\bitbox{12}{\textbf{Vertical Alignment}}& \bitbox{1}{1} & \bitbox{1}{2}& \bitbox{1}{3}& \bitbox{1}{4}& \bitbox{1}{} & \bitbox{1}{5}& \bitbox{1}{}& \bitbox{1}{}& \bitbox{1}{6} & \bitbox{1}{7}& \bitbox{1}{8}& \bitbox{1}{9}& \bitbox{1}{} & \bitbox{1}{10}& \bitbox{1}{}& \bitbox{1}{}& \bitbox{2}{11} & \bitbox{2}{}& \bitbox{2}{}& \bitbox{2}{}& \bitbox{2}{} & \bitbox{2}{}& \bitbox{2}{}& \bitbox {2}{}\\
\end{bytefield}
\end{center}
```

I have this table with the \bitbox and I want to remove the vertical lines from the table. Is it possible, or should I use the \multirow format?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Yes i think `\multirow` could be a better approach, but i don't know `bitbox`(never used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you used `bytefield` for this table, because you wanted control over the width of the columns. This can also be done with `tabular`s (see below).

But first: `\bitbox` has an optional argument, used to set the lines which should appear. Here `l` is for the left line, `r` for the right, `t` for the top, and `b` for the bottom line. By default they are all set (`[lrtb]`). By
typing `\bitbox[tb]` only the horizontal lines are drawn. Unfortunately, this has to be done for every box, because it can't be set globally.

In the first example I took the freedom to remove most but not all vertical lines. I also adjusted the bit width, so the `10` is not that squeezed anymore. And I corrected/adjusted the number of columns. It now looks like this:

[image]

In the second example I removed all vertical lines and also used `\bitboxes`, which makes it much easier to type this.

[image]

For the third example I used the `tabular` environment. In the preamble a new column type is defined for a centered column with a given width. And also a shortcut for all the necessary `\multicolumn`s. It looks pretty much
like the second example, but the lines on top and bottom of the table are a bit thicker. For this the `booktabs` package was used.

Here the code for all three examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

% packages for tabular example
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% fixed width column, centered
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
% save some work typing
\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
% example 1
\begin{center}
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.1em]{43}
\bitbox{11}{\textbf{Made Classification}} &
\bitbox{8}{Water} & 
\bitbox{8}{Air} &
\bitbox{16}{Chromium} \\

\bitbox{11}{\textbf{Classification Control}} &
\bitbox[tb]{4}{NNG} & \bitbox[tbr]{4}{On/off} &
\bitbox[tb]{4}{NNG} & \bitbox[tbr]{4}{On/off} &
\bitbox[tb]{8}{NNG} & \bitbox[tbr]{8}{On/off} \\

\bitbox{11}{\textbf{Compressing Interval}} &
\bitbox[tb]{2}{R} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{S} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{R} & \bitbox[tbr]{2}{S} &
\bitbox[tb]{2}{R} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{S} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{R} & \bitbox[tbr]{2}{S} &
\bitbox[tb]{4}{R} & \bitbox[tb]{4}{S} & \bitbox[tb]{4}{R} & \bitbox[tbr]{4}{S} \\

\bitbox{11}{\textbf{Compatibility Fan}} &
\bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tbr]{1}{F} &
\bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{V} & \bitbox[tbr]{1}{F} &
\bitbox[tb]{2}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{V} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{F} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{V} & \bitbox[tbr]{2}{F} \\

\bitbox{11}{\textbf{Vertical Alignment}} &
\bitbox[tb]{1}{1} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{2} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{3} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{4} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{}  & \bitbox[tb]{1}{5} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{}  & \bitbox[tbr]{1}{}  &
\bitbox[tb]{1}{6} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{7} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{8} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{9} & \bitbox[tb]{1}{}  & \bitbox[tb]{1}{10}& \bitbox[tb]{1}{}  & \bitbox[tbr]{1}{}  &
\bitbox[tb]{2}{11}& \bitbox[tb]{2}{}  & \bitbox[tb]{2}{}  & \bitbox[tb]{2}{}  & \bitbox[tb]{2}{} & \bitbox[tb]{2}{}  & \bitbox[tb]{2}{}  & \bitbox[tbr]{2}{}  \\
\end{bytefield}
\end{center}

% example 2
\begin{center}
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=1.1em]{43}
\bitbox[tb]{11}{\textbf{Made Classification}} &
\bitbox[tb]{8}{Water} & 
\bitbox[tb]{8}{Air} &
\bitbox[tb]{16}{Chromium} \\

\bitbox[tb]{11}{\textbf{Classification Control}} &
\bitboxes[tb]{4}{{NNG}{On/off}{NNG}{On/off}} & \bitboxes[tb]{8}{{NNG}{On/off}} \\

\bitbox[tb]{11}{\textbf{Compressing Interval}} &
\bitboxes[tb]{2}{RSRSRSRS} & \bitboxes[tb]{4}{RSRS} \\

\bitbox[tb]{11}{\textbf{Compatibility Fan}} &
\bitboxes[tb]{1}{VFVFVFVFVFVFVFVF} & \bitboxes[tb]{2}{VFVFVFVF} \\

\bitbox[tb]{11}{\textbf{Vertical Alignment}} &
\bitboxes[tb]{1}{{1}{2}{3}{4}{}{5}{}{}{6}{7}{8}{9}{}{10}{}{}} & \bitboxes[tb]{2}{{11}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}} \\
\end{bytefield}
\end{center}

% example 3
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c@{\hspace{1em}}*{16}{@{}P{1.1em}}*{8}{@{}P{2.2em}}@{}}
\toprule
Made Classification &
  \mc{8}{Water} &
  \mc{8}{Air} &
  \mc{8}{Chromium} \\
\midrule
Classification Control &
  \mc{4}{NNG} & \mc{4}{On/off} &
  \mc{4}{NNG} & \mc{4}{On/off} &
  \mc{4}{NNG} & \mc{4}{On/off} \\
\midrule
Compressing Interval &
  \mc{2}{R} & \mc{2}{S} & \mc{2}{R} & \mc{2}{S} &
  \mc{2}{R} & \mc{2}{S} & \mc{2}{R} & \mc{2}{S} &
  \mc{2}{R} & \mc{2}{S} & \mc{2}{R} & \mc{2}{S} \\
\midrule
Compatibility Fan & 
  V & F & V & F & V & F & V & F &
  V & F & V & F & V & F & V & F &
  V & F & V & F & V & F & V & F \\
\midrule
Vertical Alignment & 
  1  & 2 & 3 & 4 &  & 5  &  &  &
  6  & 7 & 8 & 9 &  & 10 &  &  &
  11 &   &   &   &  &    &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```